# Should we vote/close old Shopping questions?

Tags: discussion

I searched Meta hoping for a direct answer to this one, but so far I'm only finding semi-related Meta questions.

Here's the sequence that led me to this question.

I saw this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/513768/2-port-dual-monitor-hdmi-kvm-switch

Which I voted to close as Not Constructive (Shopping).

There was a related question on the side here: [Recommendations for a two port KVM switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/25630/recommendations-for-a-two-port-kvm-switch?rq=1)

Which I then went to and voted to close as Not Constructive as well.

Which also led me (again on the side links) to this one: [Need recommendations for KVM with mixed PS/2 and USB ports](https://serverfault.com/questions/34048/need-recommendations-for-kvm-with-mixed-ps-2-and-usb-ports?rq=1)

Which I then went to and voted to close as Not Constructive as well.

So...the real question here is...should I even bother with this kind of "clean up"?  Or is it simply busy work with no real benefit to the SF community?  I figure there are lots of layers deep in situations like this that could cause questions from years ago that nobody even cares about today to suddenly show up in the Review area.

Comment: I guess a big thing is 'what's acceptable' gets refined over time. Cleanups are *never* wasted tho as long as there's a good reason

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yup! I do when I come across them.

The topicality of the site changes over time, and it's important that users don't point to old questions as a justification for new off-topic ones. You know, the "broken window" effect, and all.

Answer (score 9):

Yes